# Starting a Workout log app

Tags: android, logging, calendar

I'm starting a project, which is a work out log on Android. I want the app to use a calender and when the user clicks on a the box of the date they want edited, they are able to add an exercise and how many reps and sets they completed. My question is do I have to create a calender from scratch or is there a way to use one built into Android?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) before. It should work really well for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView, which hooks into the CalendarProvider.